# Caching a Map variable and accessing it across four tomcat servers (java)

Tags: java, tomcat, caching, memory, server

I have a case where I need to frequently update and retrieve values of a map. This variable should have the same keys and values throughout all four servers. If one server updates the Map, it should be reflective in the other servers.

I believe I should be caching this..

Can I have some example codes in how I should be achieving this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a distributed cache. Choosing one is another issue...
see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486895/distributed-caching).

Example of using EhCache  - [here](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/code-samples.html#using-caches).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use any distributed cache for it, i.e. Hazelcast implementation for [distributed map](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/1.9/manual/html/ch02s03.html)
You could setup a Hazelcast cluster and implement [MapStore](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/map-persistence.html)

Also you will need to configure Hazelcast clients on each tomcat server. This clients will load distributed map and take care of syncing the data.

Hazelcast has a great [documentation](https://hazelcast.com/use-cases/caching/) and plenty of examples so it should be easy for you to deal with it.